# pytest collecting test cases but not executing the script

Tags: python, linux, pytest, pytest-markers

[image]

I am trying to run a pytest script like this :

`pytest myfile.py -m marker_name -v -s --disable-warnings`

pytest.ini contains the marker name as :

```
[pytest]
markers =
    marker_name: run marker_name scenario
```

But I am getting the above output. The marker seems to have been collected but is deselected.
Can anyone provide any insights onto this?

Comment: How did you add the marker to the test?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you did not add the marker to the test file at all.
From your description how you run the test file, you would only run the tests, marked with the `marker_name`, but you do not have any tests marked correctly.

You need to mark the tests with `@pytest.mark.marker_name`.

I use for example following marker in my `pytest.ini` file:

```
markers =
    soup: marks tests as soup tests (deselect with '-m "not soup"')
```

In my "test_dummy.py" file I use the marker like that:

```
@pytest.mark.soup
def test_software_lib_of_unkown_provenance():
    ## some code
```

To exclude the soup tests I run:

```
pytest myfile.py -m "not soup"
```

To only run the soup tests I do:

```
pytest myfile.py -m soup
```

See also here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html